# suggest a way to deploy server applications in node.js fast and automatically to the cloud

Tags: git, node.js, deployment

I am new to deploying the node.js server from local environment to the aws cloud, everytime I made a change to the local environment, I have to upload the local change to web through WinSCP, but it costs too much time and efforts.

Can people suggest a automatic way to sync the local environment with web environment, I think github is a way, I know how to upload the local environment with github, but how to make the cloud sync with github repository automatically ?

Comment: I'm not sure why it takes too much time and effort (unless you're always sending the entire environement?) AWS offering: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a post-receive hook for your git repository, (Guthub help - https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks)
its a script that runs after you push new commits, so you can write a shell script for automatic deployment.

You can do something like this:

1) you push new code to Github / Bitbucket / any other git server

2) post-receive hook is triggered

3) post-receive triggers a script on your AWS machine which calls git pull from the code dir. it can also restart the running server.